# Trying to compare string and double

Tags: java, string, syntax, double

I have a loop here reading in a double value, but for the program I need to compare it to the character q and if the user enters q, the loop will end. I'm not exactly sure what to do here.

```
while (currencyValue != 'q')
     {
         System.out.printf("Formatted currency value: $%,.2f\n", currencyValue);
         System.out.print("Enter a currency value or enter q to quit: ");
         currencyValue = stdIn.nextDouble();
     }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Reverse it: read a string, check if it's q, and if not, try parsing it as a double.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited, forgot to leave the loop if u press q*

Edited #2 I will put everything, just in case :)

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Currency 
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      String currencyValue=null;
      while (!currencyValue.equals("q"))
      {
          System.out.print("Enter a currency value or enter q to quit: ");
          currencyValue = stdIn.nextLine();
          if(currencyValue.equals("q")) {
              System.out.println("You pressed q, have a nice day");
              return;
          }
          System.out.printf("Formatted currency value: $%,.2f\n", Double.parseDouble(currencyValue));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I fixed now, should be working. Have in mind that you have to put the main method above, i suppose that you used that so i haven't put it.

Comment: That's not working for me either, I'm just trying to format the user entering a set of numbers like 12345. Which will be translated to $12,345.00 and when they're ready to quit doing that they hit q and it will end the while loop. The problem is, is that parsing the currencyValue variable to double isn't working either.

Comment: I think I found my problem, "(currencyValue != "q")". Since I'm comparing two strings should I be using currencyValue.notequals q?

Comment: I know how to check if strings are equal to each other, but I don't know how to check if they're not equal to each other.

Comment: I forgot to edit that part that you did, my bad, try while (!currencyValue.equals("q")) {

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped a lot.